Wiring for garage heater
I'm installing a 240V, 7500-watt (corrected) garage heater. The heater will be on its own circuit.  I have a few questions:

Can I use 2-wire with ground cable when the heater doesn't need a neutral, or does code require I have a neutral wire even if not used?
I find that there are various 30 amp outlet/plug blade configurations, some with 3 prongs and some with 4 prongs. Beyond that, some configurations rated for 30 amps have horizontal prongs, and some have angled prongs.  I'm pretty confident that I should use a 3-prong if there is no neutral, but beyond that does the electrical code specify which plug configuration I use?


Two hots plus ground is NEMA 6.  Two hots plus neutral is NEMA 10 and is ban for new circuits.  So you want a NEMA 6 or NEMA 14, but NEMA 6 is perfect for a heater, or you can hardwire the heater and do away with needing a GFCI breaker for a garage receptacle

250 watts is what a single heat lamp used iin a bathroom setup uses.. Are you sure that is enough to heat a garage?

You should only use a 240v 30A circuit for heaters drawing between 3840 and  5760 watts (81% of a 20A circuit up to 80% of 30A).

If the cost isn't much different, run the neutral even if it's not currently needed.  Your future self (or someone else if they put something else on that circuit in the future) will thank you.

Quite sure the 250w is a typo the OP made by mistake.

I'm installing a 240V, 7500-watt garage heater. The heater will be on its own circuit.
That one line contains all the information needed to properly install:

240V

A heater will almost certainly not need a neutral (unless it is a tiny 120V heater, of course). So that means two hot wires plus ground. If cables are allowed (as opposed to wires in conduit) then you can use standard black/white cable (with ground) and mark the white on each end with black or red tape to indicate it it is a hot wire.

7500W

Because a heater can be on for a long time, they are considered continuous loads and require an 80% (or 125%, depending on your point of view) derate. As a result, many appliances are designed to take 80% or just slightly under 80% of a typical breaker/circuit size. That means 16A for a 20A circuit, 24A (typical clothes dryer) for a 30A circuit, 32A for a 40A circuit. As it happens 7500W / 240V = 31.25A, which fits quite nicely on a 40A circuit.

On its own circuit

This is important. Appliances on a shared circuit are mostly plug/cord connected. There are some exceptions (e.g., lighting on a lighting/receptacle circuit, since most lighting doesn't require all that much power; multiple small heaters on a right-sized larger circuit), but when a circuit is not shared and the devices are permanently attached (water heater, HVAC, heaters like this garage heater) it makes sense to hardwire it. At a minimum, that provides a much simpler and more reliable connection than a cord/plug/receptacle. In addition, if the heater instructions specify hardwiring then you have to do that anyway. Like EV charging, a receptacle for a large heater needs to be high-quality and installed properly or it will have problems under heavy usage.
Which brings us to:

Wire Size/Type

A 40A connection will use 8 AWG wire based on this ampacity table whether copper cable, copper wire or aluminum wire. While aluminum at the breaker end is always fine, check the heater specifications as to whether it can be used with aluminum wire or only copper. You may have local rules prohibiting aluminum wire use in branch circuits as well.
Individual wires are protected from damage by conduit (certain types, ask if you need more details). Cable needs to be protected if it is below a certain height. That is likely not a problem if your heater, as is typical with large garage heaters, is mounted near the ceiling.

GFCI

This is a big deal as GFCI for 240V circuits has to be at the breaker, and those breakers are relatively expensive. If you use a receptacle then under NEC 2023 you must have GFCI protection. If you hardwire, which you almost certainly should do for other reasons, then you probably don't need GFCI, but the rules are a bit confusing and vary quite a bit depending on NEC version and local exceptions. If you are not sure, provide your NEC version (generally state dependent) and specific jurisdiction and we might be able to figure it out. (Or one of the code experts may tell me that hardwired heaters just don't need GFCI at all yet unless outdoors. I'm just not sure.)
